# End selector with several classes

Tags: css

My HTML code fragment:

```
<div class="random-xxx-class1 sdfgsdfg-class2">test</div>
```

CSS:

```
div[class$='ss2'] {
  background-color: red
}
```

It works well, but for:

```
div[class$='ss1'] {
  background-color: red
}
```

Didn't work.

How can I use CSS for end class which is not last class in DIV without adjusting order?

Comment: Have you tried `div[class*='ss1']`?

Comment: If you don't do anything specific for class sdfgsdfg-class2, you could change the order of the classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with something like

```
div[class$="ss1"], div[class*="ss1 "] {
```

That will handle any class attribute ending in `ss1` (the final class in the list) or containing a class ending in `ss1`, potentially followed by other classes.